# Not able to play Vimeo video in full screen when opening with InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic3, vimeo, inappbrowser, vimeo-android

We are using cordova-plugin in-app-browser, as part of ionic -native in our project. to open external links in the in-app-browser.

Whenever the external link contains vimeo video, it doesnt work with the in-app-browser. In android neither does it go full screen, nor do I see the option to make it full screen. Also, I do not see the pause and play controls once the video starts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are playing video using vimeo video player link which like "https://player.vimeo.com/video/Video_ID". It plays video with presetting as you set in Vimeo. If you use Vimeo Video Source Link which likes   "https://player.vimeo.com/external/Video_ID.hd.mp4?s=2fba2c67210955b7769b89e8ffdl01bcd2a&profile_id=7432" , you can use video as you wish without cross origin or full screen restriction with your own player.